# My custom REST endpoint is returning double encoded JSON. How can I make it stop?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

Here is my current controller:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/monitor')
global with sharing class TheController {

    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet() {

        Map<String, Object> status = new Map<String, Object>();
        status.put('key', 'value');
        return JSON.serialize(status);
    }
}
```

But this controller double encodes my json.

I found that sObjects are [automatically serialized](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST) in rest endpoints:

> When returning sObjects they are automatically serialized to JSON:

With that in mind I tried a controller like this one:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/monitor')
global with sharing class TheController {

    @HttpGet
    global static Map<String, Object> doGet() {

        Map<String, Object> status = new Map<String, Object>();
        status.put('key', 'value');
        return status;
    }
}
```

but then received the following error:

> Save error: Invalid type for Http* method: 
>    Map.Object

What is the correct way to format a response for my REST endpoint?

Answer (score 3):

The serialization seems to require type information up front. So `Map<String, String>` would compile but is probably not what you want.

You can create simple inner classes with just properties and return graphs of those. I have implemented some REST APIs that way.

You can also do the serialization yourself by following this pattern:

```
@HttpGet
global static void get() {
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    if (res == null) {
        res = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.response = res;
    }
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(myObjectGraph()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative to Keith C; I do the following (letting SFDC do the serializing for me)

```
 //  -------------------------------------------------------
 //  INNER CLASS ResponseWrapper : SFDC Apex Rest feature automatically serializes an instance of this class into JSON response to client
 //  -------------------------------------------------------
 global class ResponseWrapper {
    // my object graph goes in here
 }

  @HttpGet
  global static ResponseWrapper doGet () {      // corresponds to R in CRUD
  ResponseWrapper    respW    = new ResponseWrapper();
  RestRequest        restRqst    = System.RestContext.request;  
  RestResponse      restResp    = System.RestContext.response;

  // do my GET operations, building up member variables within ResponseWrapper
  restResp.statusCode = 200; // if you have errors, set this to something else like 400
  return respW;  // sfdc rest will serialize this for you
}
```